# Find active record on the bases of any other id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to find records on the bases of `demo_id` from Demojobs model.

```
def show
    @demojob = Demojob.find params[:demo_id] #instead of params[:id]
end
```

but it shows a error `Couldn't find Demojob without an ID`

Comment: Make sure `params[:demo_id]` is present.

Comment: @MarekLipka yeah its sure `demo_id` is present

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you seem to pass `nil` into `find` method, so I would double-check if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.find_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

```
@demojob = Demojob.find_by(demo_id: params[:demo_id])
```

EDIT:

For Rails version [lower than 4.0.2](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by), use:

```
@demojob = Demojob.where(demo_id: params[:demo_id]).first
```

Comment: undefined method find_by? That's interesting. What is `Demojob` then, is it even `ActiveRecord` model?

Comment: Yes!! `Demojob` is `ActiveRecord` model.

Comment: If it is an AR model, it should have `find_by` defined.

Comment: ^ Unless it's some prehistoric Rails version.

Comment: What Rails version do you use @VarinderSohal ?

Comment: @mrzasa rails version 3.2.11

Comment: Added version for old rails

Comment: @mrzasa  it shows error again `wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)`

Comment: @VarinderSohal `take` was not a method until `4.0` use `first` instead. You can also use `Demojob.find_by_demo_id(params[:demo_id])` [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/dynamic_finder_match.rb#L13) [Docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Base) Rails supported `find_by_xxx` as of `3.0` then added `find_by(hash)` in `4.0`

Comment: @engineersmnky right, `Demojob.find_by_demo_id` works in Rails 3.

Comment: @MarekLipka it works **since** rails 3 so along with `where().first` they are the most cross version applicable options.